# Let one gRpc Client calls the gRpc Server on another EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, grpc, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I'm working with three different clusters (development (1) , staging (2) and production (3)) which contains fullrest microservices.

They are EKS clusters.

Recently I created an internal grpc service which should be able to "talk" with the others clusters.
I attached an image which should clarify what I would like to achive:

[image]

As you can see, the first two cluster are part of the same VPC.
The third (and last) one lies in another VPC network.

What I would like to achive (please follow the "dashed lines" in the picture):

1. Send a gRpc requests between the first two clusters (which stand under the same VPC).
2. Send a gRpc requests "outside the VPC" on the third cluster.

How can I achive this in AWS?
Thanks for reading and for your time.

Answer (score 1):

this is a lot to do, but a high-level solutions overview looks like this.

The traffic to the pod in the cluster can be achieved by:

a) exposing the pods through the service, which is monitored by a controller (it can be aws-load-balancer-controller and I would recommend it) which creates NLB directing to it

b) exposing the pods through the service and ingress pointing to this service, which is monitored by a controller (again, aws-load-balancer-controller is great here) which creates ALB directing to it.

In your case, I would recommend creating an ingress just like documented [here on AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-a-grpc-based-application-on-an-amazon-eks-cluster-and-access-it-with-an-application-load-balancer.html).

Now, in order to allow the traffic between the two clusters, it can be achieved by exposing the LB like explained above, or implementing a service mesh like [istio](https://istio.io) or [consul connect](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect). This task is far more complicated but allows for a lot more features. This is a topic for a day of training, so let's concentrate here on traffic by ingresses (and thus, LBs).

In the same VPC the service (and thus, the pod) should be exposed using ingress of type `internal` so the traffic will not leave VPC. For the other VPC it can be reached by the Internet, or you can use VPC peering to connect those two VPCs like they are one. Then, the `internal` ALB will also be the best solution.

So, the solution would be to:

a) use aws-load-balancer-controller on all EKS clusters

b) create VPC peering

c) create ingresses for GRPC services that the pods belong to, that will spawn internal LBs

d) optionally, use your own Route53 zone and create aliases for LB records.